# How does ASEQ Studentcare work as “plan administrator” to insure Canadian students?

Tags: discussion

Ganesh S himself closed [How does ASEQ Studentcare work as "plan administrator" to insure Canadian students?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/119375/44213).

> This question needs details or clarity.

He didn't comment what was unclear?

And can a moderator close for no clarity, bypassing 5 votes?

Answer (score 2):

As with your other question, moderator votes be reversed by others casting re-open votes. I don't see any on the question so far.