# Why did GS unilaterally close these 2 questions?

Tags: discussion

[For swap-based ETFs, who will pay taxes that grow larger yearly?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/120840/10763)

> **Closed**. This question needs to be more [focused](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers.
>
> ---
>
> Update the question so it focuses on one problem only. This will help others answer the question.

[Ought you deposit fixed income in an unregistered taxable account?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/120841/10763)

> **Closed**. This question needs [details or clarity](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers.
>
> ---
>
> Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving. This will help others answer the question.

GS doesn't appear to have explained what needs more focus or clarity? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of problems with these questions, including that they are purely [quotes from other sources](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) without any explanation from you. Asking us to explain what someone else has said without explanation of what research you've already done, or how you understand what they've said, is too unclear.

Comment: Apologies if this "is too unclear" to you, but why close it unilaterally? Other users may grasp it just fine.

Comment: StackExchange is trying to build up a high quality collection of questions+answers. We've been seeing an increasing number of low quality questions recently that drown out the good ones. One of the roles of a moderator is to handle situations where the automated systems for protecting the site against low quality content are not working. As I explained on [this similar meta question](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2825/how-does-aseq-studentcare-work-as-plan-administrator-to-insure-canadian-studen), site members can reverse moderator actions with their own votes.